# Export large amount of data from Cassandra to CSV

Tags: csv, cassandra, bigdata, cassandra-2.0

I'm using Cassandra 2.0.9 for store quite big amounts of data, let's say 100Gb, in one column family. I would like to export this data to CSV in fast way. I tried:

- **sstable2json** - it produces quite big json files which are hard to parse - because tool puts data in one row and uses complicated schema (ex. 300Mb Data file = ~2Gb json), it takes a lot of time to dump and Cassandra likes to change source file names according its internal mechanism
- **COPY** - causes timeouts on quite fast EC2 instances for big number of records
- **CAPTURE** - like above, causes timeouts
- **reads with pagination** - I used timeuuid for it, but it returns about 1,5k records per second

I use Amazon Ec2 instance with fast storage, 15 Gb of RAM and 4 cores

Is there any better option for export gigabytes of data from Cassandra to CSV?

Comment: Have you considered making your own little contraption for this ? Using datastax driver you could easily make requests that extract you data then serialize them in csv file(s) with little to no java code ?
This would ensure you to get the exact result you want (for a little effort though).

Comment: Moreover, I don't get neither the method nor the problem on the "reads with pagination".

Comment: *reads with pagination* - using python driver I tried to read content using limit (tested values 100 - 10000, based on TimeUuid) and offset, it was really slow, Cassandra was able to read about 1,5k of records per second on 3 instances and replication factor 2

I cannot imagine, that simply using driver will makes possible to build fast read, because for each row Cassandra has to check on which node data are stored.

Answer (score 4):

Update for 2020th: DataStax provides a special tool called DSBulk for loading and unloading of data from Cassandra (starting with Cassandra 2.1), and DSE (starting with DSE 4.7/4.8).  In simplest case, the command line looks as following:

```
dsbulk unload -k keyspace -t table -url path_to_unload
```

DSBulk is heavily optimized for loading/unloading operations, and has a lot of options, including import/export from/to compressed files, providing the custom queries, etc.

There is a series of blog posts about DSBulk, that could provide more information & examples: [1](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading), [2](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading), [3](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/04/datastax-bulk-loader-common-settings), [4](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/06/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading), [5](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/07/datastax-bulk-loader-counting), [6](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/12/datastax-bulk-loader-examples-loading-other-locations)

Answer (score 3):

Because using COPY will be quite challenging when you are trying to export a table with millions of rows from Cassandra, So what I have done is to create simple tool to get the data chunk by chunk (paginated) from cassandra table and export it to CSV.

Look at my [example solution](https://moshimon.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/export-data-from-cassandra-to-csv/) using java library from datastax.

Comment: As I wrote before: I tried this solution, but It was very slow - it may delivered 1,5k records per second. Did You any benchmark for replica set and 100Gb of data?

Comment: The biggest table in our datasets was: 22gb of data ~ 122mil rows ~ extracted in 444m38.061s. (using 1 host cassandra server 4core 8gb ram sata hdd) (which is around 4.5k of rows / second, this is good enough for us because we only do this for migrating the data to somewhere else)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @user1859675 's answer, Here is how we can export data from Cassandra using Spark

```
val cassandraHostNode = "10.xxx.xxx.x5,10.xxx.xxx.x6,10.xxx.xxx.x7";
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
                                    .builder
                                    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host",  cassandraHostNode)
                                    .appName("Awesome Spark App")
                                    .master("local[*]")
                                    .getOrCreate()

val dataSet = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                        .options(Map("table" -> "xxxxxxx", "keyspace" -> "xxxxxxx"))
                        .load()

val targetfilepath = "/opt/report_values/"
dataSet.write.format("csv").save(targetfilepath)  // Spark 2.x
```

You will need "`spark-cassandra-connector`" in your classpath for this to work.
The version I am using is below

```
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
```