# Cassandra to Dynamo DB data migration scale issue

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, data-migration, bigdata

Problem is very simple - I want to export 1 TB data from cassandra machine to Dynamo DB because Dynamo seems like it will fit better to my data model.

Issue being faced - Cassandra data export to csv format wouldn't finish due to sheer size of data.

What is the performant way to do this ?

This is not a possible duplicate of [Export large amount of data from Cassandra to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896336/export-large-amount-of-data-from-cassandra-to-csv)
because reading data  around 1TB would be too overwhelming for a java job and would take a lot of time too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export large amount of data from Cassandra to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896336/export-large-amount-of-data-from-cassandra-to-csv)

Comment: @PseudoAj - The data scale they are discussing is around 22GB and the solution is given for the same. That wouldn't work in my case - java job will take too much time.