# Cassandra COPY TO String value incorrect

Tags: cassandra

I have these String values in Cassanrda

`select snapshot from qa;` produces

```
[{"rowKey":"6bdc3c1d-d21a-43e3-aa84-baeeda601bb3",xxxx,"lastUserAssertionDate":""}]
[{"rowKey":"6bdc3c1d-d21a-43e3-aa84-baeeda601bb3",xxxx,"lastUserAssertionDate":"2021-04-21T03:05:55Z"}]
```

Now I used `COPY qa (snapshot) TO '/data/tmp/ak1simple.csv'  with DELIMITER='|' and header=true;` to export data into csv:

Then the exported data looks like this

```
snapshot
[{\"rowKey\":\"6bdc3c1d-d21a-43e3-aa84-baeeda601bb3\", xxxx, \"lastUserAssertionDate\":\"\"}]
"[{\"rowKey\":\"6bdc3c1d-d21a-43e3-aa84-baeeda601bb3\",xxxx ,\"lastUserAssertionDate\":\"2021-04-21T03:05:55Z\"}]"
```

The second String is wrapped with "" but the first not, although both of them have no surrouding "" in Cassandra.

Anyone got an indea on this?

Comment: It's very difficult to read screenshots particularly for those of us who try to help but are on a mobile device. If I may make a friendly request, I suggest you replace the screenshots with text to make it easier for those who want to help. Cheers!

Comment: use DSBulk instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24896336/export-large-amount-of-data-from-cassandra-to-csv/62319590#62319590